# How to read excel xml file in python

Tags: python, xml, excel

I have a XML file with Excel format, like that:
[image]

How can i read data from it in python without using external modules.

Comment: Why you don't want to use external modules? As a plain text you could read this with built-in `file.read()`,

Answer (score 1):

Python has a minimal library (native) for xml:

[The ElementTree XML API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Not OP but this is the route I took to read an xml with an xls name, then rebuilt it with openpyxl into xlsx.